# expected value of a doubly stochastic matrix with i.i.d entries

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

I am now thinking a problem:

> what is the expected value of doubly stochastic matrix with i.i.d entries

Each entries is i.i.d in $[0,1]$.

Will the answer be a matrix with all entries $\frac{1}{n}$?

On the other hand, if I view this matrix as a stochastic matrix $A(k)$ and I only care about one realization. Will the time average of this realization be a matrix  with all entries $\frac{1}{n}$?

(If both answers are the same, then I could say it is ergodicity in mean.)

Comment: If the entries are i.i.d. uniform on (0,1) then the matrix is almost surely not stochastic. Please explain.

Comment: Because summation of 0.5 will exceed 1 if $n \geq 2$.  I correct my question

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. One may ask, however, what the expected value is if we impose a uniform distribution on the set of all doubly stochastic matrices (i.e. if we take a sample, every doubly stochastic matrix can be chosen with the same chance). In this case, the answer is obviously the matrix with all entries equal to $1/n$.